# AWS: Unable to drop MSSQL RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds, database-mirroring

1. We have an RDS MSSQL instance, configured as Multi-AZ.
2. I created a test DB, "Moose" on RDS.
3. After 5-10 minutes, it shows "`(Principal, Synchronized)`" in SSMS
   <= So far, so good.
4. I open a query prompt to rdsadmin (*NOT* "Moose")
   <= There are *NO* connections to the "Moose" test DB
5. `alter database Moose set partner off`
   <= RESPONSE: Commands completed successfully.
6. `drop database Moose`
   <= ERROR: *Msg 3743:
   The database 'Moose' is enabled for database mirroring. Database mirroring must be removed before you drop the database.*
7. `alter database Moose set offline`
   <= ERROR: *Msg 1468:
   The operation cannot be performed on database "Moose" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.*

Q: What's the TSQL command to "unmirror" an AWS Multi-AZ RDS database so, so I can take it offline or delete it?

---

ADDENDUM:

It appears to be a "latency issue"

- The combination of `alter database Moose set partner off` and `drop database Moose` works ... eventually.
- But `alter database Moose set partner off` won't take effect until AFTER the mirrors are fully synchronized.
- And `drop database Moose` will fail until some time AFTER "set partner off".  But at some point (assuming there's no intervening activity on the DB), I can successfully delete the MSSQL database.

Comment: You can delete the whole RDS database server without having to delete the database. I can't help with anything more detailed with MSSQL.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Deleting the entire RDS instance/nuking the RDS server is not an option.  My MSSQL admin user has full privileges to do ANYTHING at the TSQL level.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the AWS console.